# Getting started with Scala and Avro

Tags: scala, avro

I'm not to Avro (and to Scala too actually).

The way I envisage things to get started:

- write a Avro schema
- be able to read data from a `csv` file and represent them in Avro with the schema
- "dump" these to an `avro` file (later: play with Parquet)

Does not sound complicated by I'm a bit confused anyway: I assume that my application won't have to read the `avro` schema each time or for each file I want to "convert", so is there a way to have the `avro` schema "compiled" into scala code? Using SBT?

I read about `scalavro` and bits about `sbt` and avro but precise information on what to use and in what way would be appreciated.

Comment: I fear the question is not very precise, mainly due to my present lack of understanding of the problem. Any help on the problem, or on the question itself is appreciated.

Comment: I logically tie scala with spark, could you simply read CSV into a DataFrame, then write it as parquet? the DataFrame API is pretty awesome with dealing with tabular data.

Comment: @JamesTobin That's what I ended up doing :)